# Terraform: Create AWS Lightsail instance from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-lightsail

Given the Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lightsail_instance.html) on AWS Lightsail, I can construct a brand new Lightsail instance as follows.

```
resource "aws_lightsail_instance" "my_ls_instance" {
  name              = "my_ls"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"
  blueprint_id      = "ubuntu_18_04"
  bundle_id         = "2xlarge_2_0"
  key_pair_name     = "MyKeyName"
}
```

### It is possible to create a Lightsail instance from a [Lightsail snapshot](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-a-snapshot-of-your-instance) using Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. Right now Terraform can only create instances based on Lightsail blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however create an instance from snapshot in python3 /w boto3. Let me include my code:

#######

```
     import boto3
     client = boto3.client('lightsail')


     response = client.create_instances_from_snapshot(

     instanceNames=[
     'myitblog',
     ],

     availabilityZone='us-east-1a',
     instanceSnapshotName='MYITBLOG_https',
     bundleId='nano_2_0',



     )
     response = client.attach_static_ip(
     staticIpName='StaticIp-1',
     instanceName='myitblog'
     )
```